# Pyplot - add single text to xaxis (like a tick)

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Imagine you have a pyplot with a vertical line (matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline) at a specific location x. Now I would like to have a text like "COG" on the x-axis at x, like as if it was a tick. It can be either on the visible or non-visible axis or both.

However,

- ticks already exist (given array)
- shared x-axis for subplots, only lowest visible
  [image: Example Diagram - my Goal]

I though about using normal text (matplotlib.pyplot.text), but

- it would be inside the subplot
- it would not be in xaxis relation (at least I didn't find a working way so far)

I feel like manually editing the ticks to add a single item is a not so nice workaround..

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example graph of subplots from [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, -y)
```

To add the elements you wanted, you can just use `axvline` and `text`; `Text` elements can be outside of the boundaries of the graph (and in fact the tick labels are `Text`).

```
#continued from above:
axs[0].xaxis.set_visible(False)
axs[0].axvline(4.5, color='red')
axs[0].text(4.5, -.05, 'COG', color='red', transform=axs[0].get_xaxis_transform(),
            ha='center', va='top')

axs[1].axvline(4.5, color='red')
axs[1].text(4.5, -.05, 'COG', color='red', transform=axs[1].get_xaxis_transform(),
            ha='center', va='top')
```

[image]

You can instead add another tick and change its color:

```
#again, continued from the first code block
axs[0].xaxis.set_visible(False)
axs[0].axvline(4.5, color='red')
axs[0].text(4.5, -.05, 'COG', color='red', transform=axs[0].get_xaxis_transform(),
            ha='center', va='top')

ticks = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4.5, 5, 6]
labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, "COG", 5, 6]
axs[1].axvline(4.5, color='red')
axs[1].set_xticks(ticks)
axs[1].set_xticklabels(labels)
axs[1].get_xticklabels()[5].set_color('red')
```

**But**, if you don't want ticks on the top graph, then it seems like adding `Text` (as in the first example) is simplest.  Additionally, manually setting the ticks in the second example seems more verbose, and there's the issue of selecting the tick you want to change (I index with `axs[1].get_xticklabels()[5]` here, but with more ticks/nastier numbers you might need something smarter).  So I prefer the first approach better than this, but it might be useful in some cases (like if you want your line to occur *on* an existing tick).

Answer (score 0):

Using Toms´s first example leads to the desired outcome.

Additionally, for the case of an overlapping text on the label, I searched for neighboring tick labels and set their transparency != 1. Thus, the text "cog" is always visible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xV = 4.5
dxV = 1/4 # best 1/4 of the spacing between two ticks

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[0].xaxis.set_visible(False)
axs[0].axvline(xV, color='red')
axs[0].text(xV, -.05, 'COG', color='red', transform=axs[0].get_xaxis_transform(),
            ha='center', va='top')
axs[1].plot(x, -y)
axs[1].axvline(xV, color='red')
axs[1].text(xV, -.05, 'COG', color='red', transform=axs[1].get_xaxis_transform(),
            ha='center', va='top')

# Change Transparency if too close
xticks = axs[1].xaxis.get_major_ticks()
values = axs[1].get_xticks()
# values = axs[1].xaxis.get_major_locator()()
pos = np.where(np.logical_and( (xV-dxV) <= values, (xV+dxV) >= values))[0]
if pos.size > 0:
    dist = np.abs(values[pos]-xV)
    pos = pos[dist.argmin()]
    xticks[pos].label1.set_alpha(0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: XVertical @4.5]
[image: XVertical @4.75]